# Initializing vector with variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, vector, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

Basically I need template function, that would compare container's size with some constant. So I need to make std::vector of containers and check if predicate *compSize* is true.

```
template < int x, class Container >
bool compSize(Container cont)
{
    return x == cont.size();
}
    
template < int x, class ...Container >
bool compSizeMult(Container ...conts)
{
    std::vector< Container > cvector{ conts... };
    return std::all_of(cvector.cbegin(), cvector.cend(), compSize< x, Container >);
}
```

But compiler says, that parameter pack is not expanded at

> cvector{ conts... };

Also I would like to use *compSizeMult* as comparator for std::sort and make something like

```
int main()
{
    std::vector< std::vector< int > > vec{{1}, {2}, {3}, {0}, {0}};
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), compSizeMult< 0, std::vector< int > >);
}
```

that's why function is supposed to take multiple arguments. I can't use loops and lambdas in this task, only standard algorithms

Comment: Standard says that it is permissible to use variadic template in initializer list. Other answers contain code snippets, where variadic template is used in such way. But... It's just doesn't work

Comment: I've just realized that I can't use this function as comparator

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 variadics in

```
std::vector<Container> cvector{ conts... };
```

- variable `conts` which have its `...`,
- Type `Container` which doesn't have its `...` (neither in `compSize<x, Container>`).

You might want `std::common_type_t<Container...>`.

In C++17, you might use [Fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
template < int x, class ... Containers >
bool compSizeMult(Containers&&... conts)
{
    return (compSize<x>(conts) && ...);
    // or directly: return (conts.size == x && ...);
}
```

> I would like to use `compSizeMult` as comparator

It is not a valid comparer. It breaks [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering).

Comment: So I can't unpack conts into vector?

Comment: `std::vector<std::common_type_t<Container...>> cvector{ conts... };` should work (if there is a common type, you cannot mix `std::vector<int>` with `std::list<int>` with std::vector<float>`). Alternatively, you can `std::vector<std::size_t> sizes{conts.size()...};`